# add url source to clicked thumbnail jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to swap a color swatch with images and on click a thumbnail change the main image and add url surce, and the main image goes down tot the thumbnail lists and i would like to add also the main url.

THE QUESTION IS: How can i move the main url to the thumbnail clicked?

Below is my code that swap the images between thumbnail and main image and add the url source that each thumbnail have.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/neocastelli/Pn7n3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="bottlesWrapper">
  <a href="product0.html">
  <img class="MainImage" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbs">
   <img data-url="product1.html" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
   <img data-url="product2.html" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
</div>

<div class="bottlesWrapper">
  <a href="product01.html">
  <img class="MainImage" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbs">
   <img data-url="product02.html" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
   <img data-url="product03.html" src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".thumbs img").click(function(){
                            var thmb = this;
                            var src  = this.src;                    
                jQuery(thmb).parent('.thumbs').prev('.bottlesWrapper').find('img').fadeOut(400,function(){
                    thmb.src = this.src;
                    jQuery(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
                });
                jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('a').attr("href", jQuery(this).attr("data-url"));
            });
});
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, i missed to write the question. :) THE QUESTION IS: How can i move the main url to the thumbnail clicked?

Comment: main url means? your fiddle is working like that..

Comment: I don't really got what you need .... is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Pn7n3/2/

Comment: Yes is working fine, but if you pay atention when click the first thumbnail grey will change the url that that thumbnail have, and on click again will remain the same url.

Comment: I mean, the main image has url: product0.html and thumb 1 = product1.html , thumb 2 = product2.html (if i click thumb1 will change the url to product1.html and the main image will go as thumb1, this is good, but on click again thumb1 the url will not be changed to product0.html and will remain product1.html) so what i want is to put back the product0.html url

Comment: something like that, but in this example is changing the positions and at the end is adding the url to the image and remain only 1 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".thumbs img").click(function(){
                        var thmb = this;
                        var src  = this.src;                    
            jQuery(thmb).parent('.thumbs').prev('.bottlesWrapper').find('img').fadeOut(400,function(){
                thmb.src = this.src;
                jQuery(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    jQuery(this).parent('a').attr("href", $(thmb).attr("data-url"));
            });

        }); 
  })
```

Comment: Hello Pramod, is the same thing in other position :), the issue is that the main image is product0.html and on click a thumbail it will be replaced by the data-url content from thumbnail and the product0.html will dissapear, so what this need to do is to swap product0.html with product1.thml or product2.html, it depend on what thumbnail is clicked.